# Javascript difference between "=" and "==="

Tags: javascript, function

I struggle to understand the function below. I didn't know why my script wasn't working until I changed `=` with `===` in the `if` statement, as shown below. Why does `===` work while `=` doesn't?

```
var testTest = function(answer) {
    if (answer === "doggies") {
       return "My favorite animal!";
    } else {
       return "Tested";
    }
};
testTest("doggies")
```

When I type `doggies`, it shows me `My favorite animal!` With anything else, it returns `Tested` as it should.

However, when I change the `===` in the `if` statement with `=`, the `else` part doesn't work.

```
var testTest = function(answer) {
    if (answer = "doggies") {
       return "My favorite animal!";
    } else {
       return "Tested";
    }
};
testTest("elephant")
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator and `===` is a comparison operator. Now look forward for these both you will find tons of articles.

Comment: @AlexG No, this question is different. It is still a bad question, but different.

Comment: there are actually 3 different `=`, `==`, and `===`.  the first is for *assignment*, the other two are for *comparison*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick reference as you are learning JS:

```
=   assignment operator
==  equal to
=== equal value and equal type

!=  not equal
!== not equal value or not equal type
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `==` or `===` for equality checking. `=` is the assignment operator.

You can read about assignment operators here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that `=` is for assignment, after all, you are using assignment already in the first line:

```
var testTest = function(answer) {
```

and I don't think you think that this would compare anything here (or do you?).

The question remains though, why does `=` in `if (answer = "doggies")` "not work"?

An assignment is an expression. The result of that expression is the value that was assigned. Here, the result of `answer = "doggies"` is `"doggies"`, i.e. you essentially running `if ("doggies")`.

JavaScript performs **type coercion**. That means it automatically converts values of one data type to values of a different data type if necessary,  according to specific rules.

The condition of an `if` statement has to resolve to a Boolean value. But here you are using a string value as condition. The String -> Boolean conversion rules are pretty simple:

- The empty string converts to `false`.
- A non-empty string converts to `true`.

So, after type conversion, the statement is equivalent to `if (true)`, hence it will always execute the first block, never the `else` block.